# Call ui thread from static method ran on a non-ui thread

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a static method that determines what window is to be called next, but I seem to have no way to navigate to a new window. NavigationService.navigate can only be called from a non-ui thread and the dispatcher doesn't seem to be able to be stored statically and Application.Current.Dispatcher doesn't seem to exist at all in silverlight. If anybody has any tips I would be very grateful.

Edit: Found a way to store the dispatcher don't know why visual studio wouldn't let me before

Comment: Why a static method? That seems the root of all problems.

Comment: Basically the static method in combination with threading was the only way for me to solve some problems without tons of lines of code. Basically the view to be loaded depended on the application that was in use (while the code was part of a library used by multiple applications), server data that was already received and server data that was yet to be received. Storing threadstarters in a dictionary was a way to have a highly customisable navigation system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you looking for `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` available from any place

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by this sentence, its not even an answer its a question.

Comment: As I understand your question, you are looking how to store `Dispatcher` as you can't access it with `Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Comment: Yeah or something to fix the Application.Current.Dispatcher call, but as shown in the edit somehow visual studio decided that it suddenly is allowed to store the dispatcher where it wasn't before.